# Regular Expression syntax misunderstanding

Tags: python, regex

I have just started learning regex and I wanted to implement the following expression to test for operators:

```
parser = re.compile('[\+\-\*/(//)%]$')
```

I thought that the brackets around the '//' (floordiv operator in python) would mean that it would be treated as one single element of the set, but instead `parser` is matching strings like '(' and ')' and not '//'. What is the syntax for setting '//' as a standalone element of the set of characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really specify `//` in your character class.

You need to use an alternation token `|` for this.

Example:

```
//|[+*/%-]$
```

You should put the `//` first, since alternation works left-to-right.

Answer (score 2):

`|` allows any option from a set of them to be matched. So:

```
parser = re.compile('(//|[+\-*/%])$')
```

Note that you don’t need to escape `+` and `*` inside a character class – the only significant characters there are `\`, `]`, `^` at the beginning, and `-` between two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"([Blah]|//)$"
```

That's should work